# Looking for a preprocessor to fill in static files

Tags: templates, code-generation, preprocessor, html-generation

What I'm looking for would allow me to take something like this:

index.html.template:

```
<html>
<body>
<# include ("body.html.template") #>
</body>
</html>
```

body.html.template:

```
Hello World! <# include("text.txt") #>
```

text.txt:

```
4
```

And turn it into this:

```
<html>
<body>
Hello World! 4
</body>
</html>
```

While the example is HTML, I would probably end up using something like this in a lot of weird places. I think there are a number of preprocessors out there; is there a very basic one that's suited to this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/

it is basically python statements embedded in template, so you have access to all python functionality. Small example:

```
#for $i in $range(10)
#set $step = $i + 1
$step.  Counting from 1 to 10.
#end for
```

will produce

```
0.  Counting from 1 to 10.
1.  Counting from 1 to 10.
...
```

this link documents include directive: 
http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/docs/users_guide_html/users_guide.html#SECTION000860000000000000000

Comment: That could work, but it appears to only generate .py files by default. Do you have an example that generates HTML? I'm currently investigating the documentation...

Comment: @Chris actually default is Html.  I use it to generate C++ code as well.  
they are 2 modes, compile and fill.  You want later, checkout section 4.3 in documentation

Comment: @aaa sounds good. So from this it looks like I'd write cheetah compile  --iext html.tmpl --oext html to generate html?

Comment: @Chris `cheetah fill a.tmpl` Should be sufficient to create a.html

Comment: @aaa Oh, I mean as a generic system so I could do cheetah compile --iext js.tmpl --oext js, for example. Thanks for the help!